# Create bookmarks to where a header is on the page, not just to top off that page

Tags: .net, pdfsharp

I have a html file I create into a PDF.
I would like to have bookmarks that links to where the headings <\h3> is in the pdf page
not just to the page where the heading is on. I have the following code created as an example but this would not do what I want.

```
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;

namespace GenereatePDF
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreatePdf();
        }

    public static void CreatePdf()
    {
        string pdfDocumentName = "C:\\Documents\\Test.pdf";
        string htmlfile = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Documents\\HTMLstring.txt");
        var pdfDocument = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlfile, PdfConfig);
        var numPages = pdfDocument.PageCount;

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlfile);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants();
        var h3Elements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3");

        // Create a font
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 16);

        // Create first page
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.AddPage();
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
        gfx.DrawString("Page 1", font, XBrushes.Black, 20, 50, XStringFormats.Default);

        // Create the root bookmark. You can set the style and the color.
        PdfOutline outline = pdfDocument.Outlines.Add("", pdfPage, true, PdfOutlineStyle.Bold, XColors.Red);

        for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
        {
            var page = pdfDocument.Pages[i];

            string text = RemoveBlankSpaces(h3Elements[i].InnerText);
            gfx.DrawString(text, font, XBrushes.Black, 20, 50, XStringFormats.Default);

            // Create a sub bookmark
            outline.Outlines.Add(text, page, true);

            outline.DestinationPage = page;
        }

        var bytes = GetBytes(pdfDocument);
        File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDocumentName, bytes);
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
    {
        byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfDocument.Save(ms, false);
            pdfDocument.Close();
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    private static PdfGenerateConfig PdfConfig
    {
        get
        {
            var pdfConfig = new PdfGenerateConfig
            {
                PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait,
                PageSize = PageSize.A4,
                MarginTop = 60,
                MarginRight = 20,
                MarginBottom = 20,
                MarginLeft = 20
            };
            return pdfConfig;
        }
    }

    private static string RemoveBlankSpaces(string text)
    {
        string textCleaned = string.Empty;
        textCleaned = text.Replace("\r\n\t", string.Empty);

        return textCleaned;
    }
}
```

}

This is the content of HTMLstring.txt

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><style type="text/css">
            table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;}
        </style>
    </head><body>
        <h1>
            Main title
        </h1><table>
            <tr><td>Generated:</td><td>6/30/2023 6:49:43 PM</td></tr>
        </table><h2>
            John Doe
        </h2><table>
            <tr><td>Customer:</td><td>123456789</td>
            </tr><tr><td>Services:</td><td>Maintenance</td></tr>
        </table><h3>
            Heading 1
        </h3><table>
            <tr><td>Requested:</td><td>30.06.2023</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Planned:</td><td>30.06.2023</td>
            </tr>
        </table><h4>
            Result
        </h4><p>Test</p><h3>
            Heading 2
        </h3><table>
            <tr><td>Requested:</td><td>30.06.2023</td></tr><tr>
                <td>Planned:</td><td>30.06.2023</td>
            </tr>
        </table><h4>
            Result
        </h4><p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</p><h3>
            Heading 3
        </h3><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <h3>
            Heading 4
        </h3><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added line breaks here to make it over several pages as an example.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers about this! I will look into those.